# On a condition when bounded sets in $\mathbb R^n$ is convex ?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, convex-analysis

Is it true that a bounded set in $\mathbb R^n$ , $n>1$ , is convex iff every straight line  through an arbitrary interior point of the set intersects the boundary of the set in exactly two points ? I can view it geometrically , I think it is true , but am not able to write down a formal proof . Please help .

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider in the plane a "plus sign" that's one point thick, i.e., a union of line segments. It has no interior points, so your condition vacuously holds, but it's not convex.

By "a plus sign", I mean 
$$([-1, 1] \times \{ 0 \} ) \cup  ( \{ 0 \}  \times [-1, 1]).$$

Answer (score 0):

Some hints.

To simplify the topic, you can suppose your convex $C$ to be closed. Hence compact as bounded. And with a non empty interior in order to avoid your hypothesis to be void.

**Suppose $C$ convex**
Then take any point $x \in int(C)$ and a line $L$ going through $x$. The line is convex and the intersection of two convex subsets is convex. So $L \cap C$ is convex. Hence is a segment whose two endpoints are in the boundary of $C$.

**Conversely**
Needs to be done properly!