# Can a compact set of $\mathbb{R}$ have some properties and not being convex

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

The question is related to this one [On a condition when bounded sets in R n   is convex ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298161/on-a-condition-when-bounded-sets-in-mathbb-rn-is-convex/1298186#1298186).

Suppose that $n > 1 $ and that $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact (closed and bounded) set having a non empty interior. Suppose also that every straight line through an arbitrary interior point of $C$ intersects $C$ boundary in exactly two points.

Can $C$ not be convex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, such a region must be convex.

Suppose it were not convex, so that there were points $P, Q, R$ with $P, R\in C$, $Q\in\overline{PR}$, but $Q\not\in C$. Then we can WLOG assume $P, R\in int(C)$ (if not, wiggle them a little bit); now the line joining $P$ and $R$ must pass through at least three points not in $C$: a $Q_0$ on the ray $QP$ "past $P$," $Q_1=Q$, and a $Q_2$ on the ray $QR$ "past $R$."

From here it's easy to show that this line intersects the boundary of $C$ at least four times.

Comment: I'm worried by the WLOG.

Comment: Since $C$ is compact, and hence closed, there is some small open ball $B$ around $Q$ which is disjoint from $C$. Meanwhile, as long as $C$ has interior (as assumed in the OP), the interior of $C$ must be dense in $C$: otherwise, connecting a boundary point not in the closure of the interior to a point in the interior, we get a line intersecting the boundary in at least three places.

Comment: Oh, did you mean to write $P,R \in int(C)$?

Comment: Derp, yes, fixed.